# Localizing date in view Laravel 5

Tags: php, date, localization, laravel-5

I'm dealing with date localization in Laravel. Here is how i display date in blade.php.

```
Publish on {{  $post->published_at->format('F j, Y') }} //Publish on November 20, 2015
```

I tried with (https://github.com/jenssegers/date) to

```
use Jenssegers\Date\Date;

Date::setLocale('hr');
echo Date::now()->format('F j, Y'); //Studeni 20, 2015
```

and what bothers me is how can i reformat `$post->publiched_at`  in blade.php to be localized

Comment: Did you tried Carbon? http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding accessors in model

```
use Jenssegers\Date\Date;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function getDates()
    {
        return ['published_at'];
    }

  public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        return new Date($date);
    }

    public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        return new Date($date);
    }

   public function getPublishedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        return new Date($date);
    }   

}
```

and set locale in config/app.php

```
'locale' => 'hr',
```

Answer (score 1):

You can depend on locale functionality of the built-in Carbon class.

In your view you can set the locale if required

```
<?php \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale('hr');?>
```

Then you can just echo your date in the required format

```
{{$post->published_at->formatLocalized()}}
```

You can define published_at as Carbon instances directly in your Post model

```
protected $dates = ['published_at'];
```

Comment: `formatLocalized() `returns me still english date, but `diffForHumans()`returns me localized format like (1 day ago)

Comment: `$post->published_at->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y')`

Comment: Instead of Carbon setLocale try the php setlocale(LC_TIME, 'hr');

Comment: Well, again i get english localizde date

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).  They provide many flexible ways to approach this.

```
// Using a String
$dtToronto = Carbon::createFromDate(2012, 1, 1, 'America/Toronto');
$carbon = new Carbon('first day of January 2008', 'America/Vancouver');

// or a DateTime
$nowInLondonTz = Carbon::now(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
```